# UICollectionView with 3 columns doesn't produce the desired result

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I'm testing this on iPhone XR simulator. I have 3 rows of images and I want them displayed in 3 columns, 2 points distance top, left, right and bottom. This used to work but for some reason it doesn't now.

```
extension ProfileVC : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
override func size(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer, withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width / 3, height: collectionView.bounds.width / 3)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2)
}
}
```

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: So, you are have 9 images and want them to be a 3x3 grid, right? Do you want the images to all have 2 points between them and the next image as well as 2 points around the edge? Or do you want the images to touch each other, like the two images on the left, with a 2 point border around the group of images?

Comment: Also, have you verified that `ProfileVC` is in fact setup as the delegate of the flow layout in the collection view onscreen? (i.e. do these methods get called?)

Comment: @theMikeSwan oh, man. Thank you. This triggered me to check if i've set the delegate which I forgot so my method was never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing sizeForItemAt indexPath method to fix your collection view for a three columns only with item size dynamically based on screen width.
get the screen width or collection view width, then subtract your preferred spaces (8) then divide by 3 (3 columns).
Also, from your storyboard or nib file set minSpacing for lines = 2 and section insets for top = 2 and comment your above methods and implement only this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (collectionView.frame.width - 8) / 3
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to set the delegate (smh). Your solution works. Thank you